# How to fetch one by one row from sqlite database and show in EditText Box

Tags: android

I went through so many links and honestly made effort to get my answer but still messed. (May be its duplicate question)  .I inserted few rows in Sqlitedatabase successfully. I need to show every row in EditText on `Next` and `Previous` button.
below is my code

```
public List<Contact> getAllContacts() {
        List<Contact> contactList = new ArrayList<Contact>();
        // Select All Query
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
      {
            do{
            Contact contact = new Contact();
            contact.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
            contact.setName(cursor.getString(1));
            contact.setPhoneNumber(cursor.getString(2));
             contactList.add(contact);
             }while(cursor.moveToNext());
            cursor.moveToFirst();
           cursor.close();
        }
         return contactList;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cursors have a specific behavior, they start before the first result.
So you have to `moveToFirst` before doing anything :

```
public List<Contact> getAllContacts() {
    List<Contact> contactList = new ArrayList<Contact>();
    // Select All Query
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    {
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Contact contact = new Contact();
                contact.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
                contact.setName(cursor.getString(1));
                contact.setPhoneNumber(cursor.getString(2));
                contactList.add(contact);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        cursor.close();
    }
    return contactList;
}
```

Or you can just loop on `moveToNext` so at the first iteration, the cursor will point to the first result :

```
public List<Contact> getAllContacts() {
    List<Contact> contactList = new ArrayList<Contact>();
    // Select All Query
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    {
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            Contact contact = new Contact();
            contact.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
            contact.setName(cursor.getString(1));
            contact.setPhoneNumber(cursor.getString(2));
            contactList.add(contact);
        }
        cursor.close();
    }
    return contactList;
}
```

**Your code:**
button clicactivity is 
show.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
         List<Contact> contacts = db.getAllContacts();       
            for (Contact cn : contacts)
            {
                String log = "Id: "+cn.getID()+" ,Name: " + cn.getName() + " ,Phone: " + cn.getPhoneNumber();
                edit_name.setText(cn.getName());
                edit_phon.setText(cn.getPhoneNumber());
            }

         }
   });
```

Ok. So your problem here is what I though.
When you click on the button, the loop here put the name (getName()) in the `EditText` for each contact you got from database.
This iteration does this (if you have two contacts):

- It gets the first contact and puts its name into the `EditText`
- The loop goes on and gets the second contact and puts its name into the same `EditText`

At the end of this loop, you only have last contact information displayed.

You can add a `Log.d("CONTACT", cn.getName());` to see it iterate over each contact.

**So:**
Something that should work is to keep track of the latest displayed index.

```
int index = 0;

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v.getId() == R.id.previous) { // android:id="@+id/previous" on the "Previous" button
        index--;
    }
    else if (v.getId() == R.id.next) { // android:id="@+id/next" on the "Next" button
        index++;
    }
    List<Contact> contacts = getAllContacts();
    // Prevent out of bounds
    index = Math.min(Math.max(index, 0), contacts.size() - 1);
    // Fill `EditText`s with contact data
    Contact contact = contacts.get(index);
    edit_name.setText(cn.getName());
    edit_phon.setText(cn.getPhoneNumber());
}
```

Then, when you click on the "Previous" button, it displays the previous (or first if there is no previous) contact data. And when you click on the "Next" button, it displays the next (or last if there is no next) contact data.

**Note on Math uses:**
If I have 2 contacts, available indexes are `0` and `1`.

```
index = Math.max(index, 0) => So it is never < 0 (0, the first index)
                  V
index = Math.min(index, contacts.size() - 1) => So it is never > (2 - 1) = 1 (1, the last index)
```

This prevents `OutOfBoundsException` thrown when trying to get element in a `List` at an `index` in which there is no element.

Comment: Its returns only last record. i need first record at very first time and then next to next. Is there any way to give cursor position one first row,and when user click next time its move to second row and return only second record and so on.. ?

Comment: In which `variable` do you get the last record?

Comment: in my MainActivity i have a button named show. on button click  i stored return value in  List<Contact> contacts = db.getAllContacts(); after by for each loop i set the row value in EditText

Comment: I think I understand the problem. Can you add the click method code to the question so we can fix it?

Comment: Hi @Gorcyn , seems it will work perfectly .but i am unable to handle exceptions. Can u please modify your code to handle exception and please explain what is the role of  index = Math.min(Math.max(index, 0), contacts.size() - 1); I appreciate your quick response . Kindly help a little bit More. Thanks

Comment: @sachindraN.Pandey Explanation on `Math` stuff added, what exception do you encounter?

Comment: @sachindraN.Pandey You're welcome! Do not hesitate to validate the answer so others can understand the problem is solved. [This also gives me some points, but I don't really care about that]